# HOW to set permission on multiple folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, permissions, csom, jsom

I got a client that has a really dense folder structure and they want to apply permission to the different folders.

I wanted to know if there a way to apply permission to multiple folders at a time since most of the folders got the same permission.

I thought of a solution as below where I just select the folders and add the user with full control etc.

ANY other solution is welcome.

**Note** I cant put users in groups in this scenario.

[image]